# Try to make marquee scroll up with php

Tags: php, html, marquee

I have a problem if the text is longer it will not break into other line.

Any suggestion?

```
 <marquee  behavior='scroll' direction='up' scrollamount="2">
<?PHP

while ($result = mysql_fetch_array ($query))
{
  echo "<ul id='navm'><li><a>".$result["Name"]."</a></li>";
  echo "<li><a>".$result["Title"]."</a></li>";
  echo "<li><a>".$result["Information"]."</a></li>";
  echo "<li><a>".$result["Date"]."</a></li></ul>";
}

?>

</marquee>
```

Comment: First of all, you should no longer use `marquee` because it is no part of the html5 standard. If you want to let your text scroll, you should use javascript.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add CSS style to delimit the link, try the following code:

```
a:link 
{
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Source: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/